# Html [option] - быть или не быть?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть у нас метка [option](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option). Пара нюансов.

1. `option` - это не только про html, это ещё и возможно `Option` из Scala.
2. Если учесть, что у нас все вопросы по данной метке в контексте html, то другой вопрос встаёт. `option` - это не элемент, это лишь подэлемент у `select`.

   ```
   <select name="myselect">
       <option value="some-text">Some Text</option>
   </select>
   ```

   В связи с чем вопрос, если мы оставляем эту метку для вопросов про html компонент, то может стоит лучше создать метку [html-select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select), а [option](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) сделать синонимом? Или мы отталкиваемся от того, как пользователи использую метку?

Хотя, я лично вообще не вижу особого смысла по каждому компоненту отдельную метку создавать. Я бы всё к [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) синонимизировал.

Comment: А можете принять мой ответ, так как, собственно, вопрос решён?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov done ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метка [option](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) удалена. Везде заменил на [html-select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select).

Дело в том, что работа с тегом `select` довольно специфическая и заслуживающая отдельной метки тема. А тег `option` не существует отдельно без `select`.

Answer (score 13):

> Хотя, я лично вообще не вижу особого смысла по каждому компоненту
>   отдельную метку создавать. Я бы всё к [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) синонимизировал.

**Поддерживаю.** В значении "тег `<option>`" эта метка не выделяет сколько-нибудь самостоятельную* область внутри [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), чтобы оправдать её существование.

А поскольку есть явная неоднозначность с Option и Optional, а также [опциями (как "настройками") во всяком программном обеспечении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657947/python2-error-agents-option-requires-an-argument), **эту метку стоит уничтожить вовсе**.

---

* Самостоятельность области штука субъективная, но обычно может помочь следующий критерий: можете представить человека, который знает подобласть (option), но не знает надобласть (html)? Может ли такая ситуация сложиться естественным образом со случайным разработчиком?

Comment: А на мой взгляд `<option>` полезнее, чем `<div>`.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы так говорите, как будто возражаете на какую-то часть ответа. Да, отдельная метка для `<div>` ещё более бесполезна. И?

Comment: Заодно посмотрите на репутацию людей которые задают вопросы по этим меткам. В основном она ниже 100. Возможно они просто не знают как кработает ресурс и метки, и просто кликают любые лишь бы было. (П.С. я согласен что метка не нужна)

Comment: @Qwertiy А можете добавить [tag:статус-завершено]? Так как метка удалена.