# Объединить метки про картинки

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [image](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image), [img](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/img), [изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8).
Может нужно тут и [imageview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageview) добавить, не знаю зачем эта метка.

Comment: О, у нас ещё [tag:images] есть...

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, по идее [img](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/img) должно относиться к html, а [изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - к обработке изображений. Получается, что это должны быть разные теги.

Comment: есть отдельная метка html, не думаю что для каждого тэга нужно создать отдельную метку, а изображения и картинки разве не одно и тоже?

Comment: Подумать надо... Там под 1000 вопросов.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4249/15479 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6451/15479 с html тегами всё сложно