# Для чего нам [компоненты]? Объединить и удалить

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Для чего нам нужны следующие метки?

- [component](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/component) (48 вопросов),
- [компонент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82) (47 вопросов),
- [компоненты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b) (8 вопросов)

Само по себе, "компонент" — это чрезвычайно широкое понятие, и под него теоретически подпадает все что угодно. Сейчас, в основном, метки используются для элементов визуальных фреймворков.

Предложение 1, к модераторам — предлагаю **синонимизировать и объединить** все метки, по обычаю к [компоненты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b).

Предложение 2, к обсуждению — а нужны ли эти метки вообще, может быть их скопом и удалить? У нас бывают специалисты по [компонентам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc)? Вряд ли. Ни один вопрос не отмечен только одной этой меткой. И мне кажется, ни один вопрос ничего не потеряет, если метку **убрать и/или заменить** на метку визуального фреймворка.

Comment: Добавите две голосовалки: одну — по удалению, другую — по синонимизации?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov про синонимизацию и голосовать нечего, она очевидно нужна. А вот про удаление - обсудить/проголосовать стоит.

Comment: Ну если эта метка используется для вопросов о компонентах визуальных фреймворков, то я могу скомбинировать две метки и указать название этого фреймворка и сабжа, чтобы обозначить свой вопрос как о компоненте фреймворка. Без этой метки, чтобы сохранить прежнюю возможность, полагаю, придётся делать уникальную метку на каждый из существующих в базе стака визуальных фреймворков. Просто логическое рассуждение.

Comment: @Diskyp Двух меток - с указанием фреймворка и типа элемента будет достаточно и они будут куда более описательны чем "фреймворк + [компонент]".

Comment: Сделал основной метку [tag:компоненты].

Comment: @Qwertiy А вы метки дополнительно объединили? А то, как я понимаю, вы их только синонимизировали, так как я вижу вопросы с несколькими метками или неосновной.

Answer (score 12):

Если посмотреть, какие вопросы задают по этим меткам, наблюдается явное преобладание вопросов о компонентах UI, пользовательских интерфейсов. Беда в том, что компонентов из очень разных технологий, и, если взять пересечение всех множеств знаний, которые эти вопросы (исключив те, что не о UI) охватывают, ничего осмысленного не останется.

И в целом, "компонент" термин очень общий, область знаний вокруг него полностью определяется тем, о компоненте **чего** идёт речь (**это что-то** стоит отразить меткой). Что этой меткой отфильтровывают два подписчика [component](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/component), не представляю. У двух других меток подписчиков нет вовсе.

**Посему, предлагаю эти метки удалить.

...и внести в чёрный список, чтобы они не возникли снова.**

Для компонентов UI можно использовать метку [ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui), если хочется.

Comment: Так там 90% именно о ui речь. Чем не угодило-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy кхм... Я в ответе вроде именно об этом и написал?

Comment: О чём? Ты написал "если исключить вопросы по ui, то эти метки не нужны, поэтому их надо удалить". Так почему вопросы по ui не заслуживают метки?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что для них следует использовать метку [tag:ui], например? В работе с компонентами разных UI-систем практически нет осмысленных точек соприкосновения, о которых и только о которых можно задать осмысленный вопрос.

Comment: Да и то, метка UI это скорее для вопрос о User Interface вцелом (см. тематику ux.SE). Существующие же вопросы логичнее поотмечать метками тех типов контролов, о которых они заданы (прогрессбары, кнопки, комбобоксы чекбоксы и т.п.)

Comment: @Kromster главное [не увлечься](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6451/181100) только, а так да.

Comment: @Kromster, все современные js-фреймвёркм используют компонентный подход и понятие компонента. Причём, все примерно одинаково. А вот метка ui тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: @Qwertiy PS: я нигде не писал "если исключить вопросы по UI". Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: @D-side, в 90% случаев метка используется вполне однозначно. Не вижу причин её удалять.

Comment: @Qwertiy то, что она однозначна, не означает, что от неё есть польза. Насколько сильно эта метка сужает область вопроса в дополнение к метке фреймворка, о компонентах которого речь?

Comment: @D-side, сужает собственно до компонентов ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy а там много есть чего обсуждать кроме них? :)

Comment: @D-side, да полно.

Comment: @Qwertiy окей. Всё ещё остаётся проблема самостоятельности метки.

Comment: @D-side, можно как-то переименовать, но у меня название не придумывается.

Answer (score -3):

Как правило, компонентный подход предполагает изоляцию, инкапсуляцию и поток данных. Не вижу причин удалять эти метки.

Comment: Изоляцию и инкапсуляцию предполагает все что угодно (даже водопровод, театр и укладка волос). Потоки данных (в узком смысле) тут не при чем, а в широком - опять же вездесущи.

Comment: @Kromster, и что?

Comment: То, что такой аргумент в пользу сохранения метки кажется не состоятельным.